# Transcript in bad print

Tags: masters, application, rejection, transcript-of-records

I am going to apply for MS programs in The US and the transcripts I received for my bachelors from my former university are just xerox of my original marksheet with verification stamp and sign of director of examinations.

The issue is that since it is a xerox the print quality is not that good. At one place my name is not clear but at other pages ot is clear. The letters mix up due to being printed too close.

Overall it is readable though.

What should I do?
Will my application get rejected because of this reason?

Answer (score 1):

That would be very unlikely in normal circumstances. But it would be worth some effort to have the transcript sent directly to the places you apply to rather than show them your copy, assuming that is what you mean here. It will then be clear (even with a bad copy) that the transcript is official and hasn't been altered.

I think most places will do this, though there might be a fee.

Answer (score 1):

I am on such admissions committees and I see such copies quite often. If I can read the parts relevant to the admissions process, then there is no problem.